# Is it preferable to use lexical dirhandles in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

Chapter 10 of Perl Best Practices recommends not using baseword filehandles but instead using indirect filehandles assigned to a lexical variable when opening a file.

Similarly, when opening a directory, is it also best to use an indirect dirhandle assigned to a lexical variable instead of a bareword dirhandle?

**Edit** I don't consider this a simple "opinion" type of question as this goes to improving the robustness of my code using published recommended practises.

Comment: The big reason for using lexical handles over typeglobs is that the latter are global in scope. That is the same whether you use them for files or directories.

Comment: "indirect" file handles?

Comment: What's an *indirect* handle? You mean a lexical variable?

Comment: Apparently that's what Damian Conway called lexical filehandles in the [2005 edition of PBP](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&pg=PT226&lpg=PT226&dq=perl+best+practices+indirect+filehandle&source=bl&ots=Hl6dkJuwkt&sig=Gq5Cj599onMP91KsTKdHYhvFGt0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B38PU6GIEMKRygHJ7YDwBA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=perl%20best%20practices%20indirect%20filehandle&f=false) (not sure about other editions since that's the first thing a Google search turned up).

Comment: Yes. Damian Conway calls them "indirect filehandles" (see section "Indirect Filehandles") which are created by the open and are then assigned to a "lexical variable" for later use. Calling them "lexical filehandles", as DC does later on in PBP, is clearer IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking about using a lexical variable (`opendir(my $dh, ...)`) instead of a named glob (`opendir(DH, ...)` aka `opendir(*DH, ...)`).

Lexical variables are scoped to a block or file, while named globs are global. That means that `opendir(DH, ...)` is to `opendir(my $dh, ...)` as `our $x` is to `my $x`.

In programming, you always want to use the smallest scope possible, so lexical variables are usually the better choice.